# How to Import Shapefiles (or any dataset) to a webmap using Openlayers/GeoExt online? WFS-T

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

I tried Using Heron, But it didn't workout well. The problem is, I couldn't found any good documentation about this matter. I just want to "Update" DataSet using an UpLoad tool to my actual Database.
I'm using GeoExt 1 / ExtJs 3.4 / Openlayers 2 and Geoserver.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the Shapefile into QGIS, then export a webmap (Openlayers or Leaflet) using the qgis2web plugin. It also allows you to upload directly to the web via FTP.